# Why will my JTable display on a new JFrame but not on my existing JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, jtabbedpane

I am working with JDBC.
My Class has a JFrame with a JTabbedPane to display my JPanels with the UI's for my different methods.
On this panel I want to display a result set in a JTable with to additional columns of buttons.
This is all currently working when I display it on a new JFrame but not when I try to display it on the existing one. Could somebody please explain why.

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    contentPane.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Main", null, panel, null);
    panel.setLayout(null);


JTable table = new JTable(model);

    DisplayButtonColumn testWithButtons1 = new DisplayButtonColumn(table,
            displayHandler.getColCount());
    DisplayButtonColumn testWithButtons2 = new DisplayButtonColumn(table,
            displayHandler.getColCount() + 1);

    panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));

//      JFrame f = new JFrame();
//      f.setSize(1000, 500);
//      f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
//      f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Where is the panel added to the frame?

Comment: not enough info - please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
panel.setLayout(null);
```

The problem is the `null` layout. *Don't do that*. Swing is designed to be used with layout managers and not doing that will lead to trouble almost without exception. Using absolute layout would require you to manually manage the bounds to the components, and you're not doing that. If you need something else than the default `FlowLayout`, just create one that matches your needs:

```
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

(It would be also possible to add to `JTabbedPane` without the helper panel, but I suppose you want more components in the tab).

Comment: Thank you this is working for both BorderLayout and FlowLayout but not in the way that I want the JTable is not using the full JPanel's size it is being squeezed into the centre of the panel and only using about 1/3 of the space available
Any idea how to rectify this

Comment: @Dáire That's odd. Placing a component to the center position (the default) at `BorderLayout` should expand it to all available space. Get rid off any `setSize()` calls, and remember to call `frame.pack()` before setting it visible. You'll also likely want to call `table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);`.

Comment: Thanks I have it fixed. Eclipse auto generated a line of code and that's what caused the problem Thanks again.